# What to do with git-p4 remote branches after migration?

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I have a vague understanding of the meaning of refs/remotes/p4/master when migrating from P4 to Git (documentation isn't very clear about it, and I couldn't find an explanation here).

According to *git-p4 clone* documentation:

> Imports the full contents of the head revision from the given p4 depot
>   path into a single commit in the Git branch refs/remotes/p4/master.

If I understand correctly, Git somehow uses the refs/remotes to track the local Git repository that was created with the original P4 repository (please correct me if I'm mistaken).

My questions are: if after the migration I do not want to maintain the connection between Git and P4 - should I delete the ref/remotes/p4/master branch? Or should I move it? Does it even have any effect? Maybe it's better to just leave it there just to be safe...?

Note: I will later need to migrate more branches of the same project from Perforce to Git, but again, once a branch is migrated, I will not need to track it in Perforce any longer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem in keeping the remote branches because they are only pointers to data that exists in your git repository. To see this, open the files inside the following folder in your workspace:

```
.git/refs/remotes/p4
```

The existing files simply have the SHA corresponding to the relevant commit object. So removing these pointers will not break anything in your repository, but might make it difficult to import new changes from the P4 server or submit new ones.

I suggest that you import all branches from P4 in one go, instead of doing that multiple times. Read the [BRANCH DETECTION](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4#_branch_detection) section of the [git-p4](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4) documentation to learn on how to do this.